# Alternative to StatSVN?

Tags: svn, jenkins-plugins, statsvn

I am using [StatSVN](http://statsvn.org/) to generate a graph & table for SVN, but it is taking too long.

Is there any StatSVN plugin for Jenkins that is faster or an alternative to StatSVN that is faster?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SvnStat](http://sourceforge.net/projects/svnstat/), which is *much* faster than [StatSVN](http://statsvn.org/) in my experience - an order of magnitude or more.

In StatSVN's defense, it also outputs *much* more detailed repo information than SvnStat - e.g. commit logs and useful directory & file statistics among others; but this is not always worth the extra time to run it.

Personally, I find *both* StatSVN and SvnStat useful and frankly complimentary, but people's needs and situations can differ of course.

*If you still want the extra detail that StatSVN provides*, you could also consider two options (one, the other, or both):

1. Limit the verbose log that StatSVN analyzes - e.g. using [`svn log`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html)'s `--revision`, `--stop-on-copy`, `--limit`, `--depth`, and/or other options.
2. Use [StatSVN options](http://wiki.statsvn.org/User%20Manual.ashx) to limit its analysis - e.g. `-exclude` or `-no-developer`.

Focusing on option # 2, for example, here is a StatSVN invocation I used when I bumped into the same problem with report generation taking too long...

```
java -jar "C:\Bin\statsvn-0.7.0\statsvn.jar" ^
    "C:\SCC\SomeProject\VerboseLog.xml" ^
    "C:\SCC\SomeProject" ^
    -output-dir "C:\SCC\SomeProject\StatSVN" ^
    -include "trunk/**" ^
    -exclude "branches/**:tags/**"
```

...and decided that tags and branches were not important (but contributing to lengthy analysis).